# Image Upload Remove Auto Rotate

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to make a simple upload image and the auto rotate mess it all up. How do you upload an image ignoring the exiff/metatags info of an image file. I mean, upload it "as is" and disable auto rotate on upload? Thanks a lot. My code is just a simple file upload. `<input type="file" />`

Btw Im having problem on images taken by iphones, the portrait ones.